# Store and Search on key and value pair on appengine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I want to store multiple custom key and value pair on Google Datastore entity inside the another model as a child entity. I found that there are two ways to do it

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()
```

(or)

```
List<KeyValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<KeyValuePair>()
```

I really do not know which is correct method.

I also wanted to search by key and value pair which will be specified by the user to get the parent entity. The search also can have multiple key and value pair.

Please help me do it.

Comment: Yes, i uses java and JDO.

Answer (score 2):

Google AppEngine Datastore writes and reads only simple Java data types listed in the Java Datastore [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) documentation, not HashMap<String,String> or List<KeyValuePair> collections.  However, it is possible to iterate over these collections and store each member as a separate record.  The Datastore uses either a String or a long integer as the key (also known as ID or name) for each record.  Thus the best fit for your Java program would be a HashMap<String,String>.

As you're open to suggestions, how about using the Datastore low level API instead of JDO?  Your requirement is lightweight and a low level implementation might be simpler.  For example:

```
// Make up some sample data
java.util.HashMap<String,String> capitals = new java.util.HashMap<String,String>();
capitals.put("France","Paris");
capitals.put("Peru","Lima");
// Create the records
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService datastoreService;
datastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
for (String country : capitals.keySet()) {
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity capitalEntity;
    capitalEntity = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity("Capitals", country);
    capitalEntity.setUnindexedProperty("capital", capitals.get(country));  // or setProperty if you prefer
    datastoreService.put(capitalEntity);
}
// Retrieve one record
String wantedCountry = "Peru", wantedCapital;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query query;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery pq;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity entity;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key wantedKey;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter filter;
query = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("Capitals");
wantedKey = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey("Capitals", wantedCountry);
filter = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterPredicate(
        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
        wantedKey );
query.setFilter(filter);
pq = datastoreService.prepare(query);
entity = pq.asSingleEntity();
wantedCapital = (String) entity.getProperty("capital");
// Retrieve all records
java.lang.Iterable<com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity> entities;
java.util.Iterator<com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity> entityIterator;
query = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("Capitals");
pq = datastoreService.prepare(query);
entities = pq.asIterable(); 
entityIterator = entities.iterator();
while (entityIterator.hasNext()) {
    entity = entityIterator.next();
    String foundCountry = entity.getKey().getName();
    String foundCapital = (String) entity.getProperty("capital");
    // ... do whatever you do with the data
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have explained having collection of entities as separate entity, not in the relationship with any entity. From your example, lets say i wanted to have list of persons who belongs two or more countries. How do i get list of persons information if we only have capital of the country.

Comment: It's... complicated.  In Datastore each Entity has only one parent, enabling one-to-many relationships.  You also want the option of many-to-many relationships.  The usual way to model that in a one-to-many system is to add a third kind of Entity whose records link the other two.  I'll try to extend my first example that way.